# Mule 4: Replace recurring node value in original payload

Tags: mule, mule4

I have a recurring node/array in the JSON payload. I need to use value of the wonumber to call another service and the value from this service response has to be used to replace a code value on original message.

```json
{
  "element1": "text1",
  "element2": "text2",
  "element3": "text3",
  "InvoiceItemDTO": [
    {
      "code": "",
      "itemNo": "1",
      "wonumber": 123
    },
    {
      "code": "",
      "itemNo": "2",
      "wonumber": 456
    }
  ]
}
```

The service response will give value for code field, which has to be copied back on original payload code value.

I have applied for each loop on the recurring node to make the call to service for each block in ItemDTO. But I am concerned about putting service response value field back on the original payload at the same index for which the service call was made.

If service call returns code value as abc1, def2 for above payload, then expected final payload is:

```json
{
    "element1": "text1",
    "element2": "text2",
    "element3": "text3",
    "InvoiceItemDTO": [
        {
            "code": "abc1",
            "itemNo": "1",
            "wonumber": 123
        },
        {
            "code": "def2",
            "itemNo": "2",
            "wonumber": 456
        }
    ]
}
```

Any recommendations on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Which node is recurring? I do not see any repeating jsons in the payload. The expected output is not clear. What exactly are you "concerned" about when updating the payload? It is not very clear for which part do you need help

Comment: as you can see InvoiceItemDTO is an array, I have applied foreach to recur on InvoiceItemDTO (Collection: payload.InvoiceItemDTO. The calls to service are made using wonumber, so in above example there will be two calls made to service which will returns two codes. I need to get the values of these two codes and update the original payload with value returned from the service.

Comment: This is a much clearer explanation. So it seems like you are able to get these values but you are unable to update them in the original payload after the for loop ends

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `for-each` scope does not change the payload. If you want to retain some information gathered during execution of `for-each` you will need to store that data in a variable. As per the [official doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/for-each-scope-concept#variable-propagation)

> Every execution of the For Each scope starts with the variables and values from the previous execution of the block. New variables or modifications to existing variables that take place when processing one element are visible during the processing of another element. These changes to variables continue to be available outside the For Each scope.

For your use case you can do the following (Just a pseudo code)

1. Collect all unique `wonumber` in an array and store it in a variable
   `<set-variable variableName="wonumbers" value="#[payload.InvoiceItemDTO.wonumber distinctBy $]"/>`
2. Loop through this variable in the `for-each` scope
3. After collecting the `code` for the wonumber store that as a map in a variable so that you can access it later.

   ```xml
   <foreach collection="#[vars.wonumbers]">
     <set-variable variableName="currentWonumber" value="#[payload]" />
     <do-your-thing.... />
     <set-variable variableName="wonumbersToCodeMapping" value="#[(vars.wonumbersToCodeMapping default {}) ++ (vars.currentWonumber): payload.code //however you are getting the code]"/>
   </foreach>
   ```
4. Using the `wonumbersToCodeMapping` you can update the payload using [`update`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-operators#update-operator) operator

```js
%dw 2.0
output json
---
payload update {
   case .InvoiceItemDTO -> 
      $ map ((item) -> item  update {
            case .code -> vars.wonumbersToCodeMapping[item.wonumber as String]
      })
}
```

Comment: At step 3, I presume we want to collect all codes. However, what we have is a collection & a string value and this expression throws error:
"Unable to infer a output media type as more than one is being used: application/json,text/xml please specify using: 'output <your mime-type> --- <expr>

Comment: When you do not specifically specify the `output` of a dataweave expression. it tries to automatically derives it and if it is not able to do so it throws that error. This was a pseudo code I was not expecting it to work. you just need to specify the output of the expression and it should solve it

Comment: If it matters, the response from SOAP Webservice is:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><ns1:readResponse xmlns:ns1="http://somenamespace.com"><ns1:out><ns2:customAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://anothernamespace.com" /><ns2:warningsAndInformation xmlns:ns2="http://onemore.com" /><ns1:code>abc100</ns1:code></ns1:out></ns1:readResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope

Comment: yeah it will not change the output that you need to define. You just need to change the `payload.code` part accordingly